# How I manage node version using NVM?

Tags: version-control, nvm

I want to use multiple version of node in my system so is this possible to do using `NVM`.

Also how I remove unused `Node` version from my system without affecting other version.

suggestions are welcome for Windows system.

Comment: Have you searched? There are plenty of resources detailing exactly this.

Comment: Yes i already search about this I know their are many examples related to my question but In my windows system its not work properly I successfully do this in Ubuntu system but windows create issue.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: ERROR open \settings.txt

Comment: Please post enough so that we can replicate the problem. I've no idea what `settings.txt` is.

Comment: Okay even I face this issue for the first time that's why I put here I hope I get some solution I want someone to tell me the actual process so I found my mistake and solve the issue.

I am also a developer I know we should first google it out and then if you not get the perfect solution put your views over forms or somewhere you hope for solution.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I'm asking for enough to replicate the issue :)

Comment: Yes, you can do this also in some pleasant way sir, I need to know the actual process other errors aeries due to same mistake are solve by me only I am not expecting someone come with spoon and feed me. my intention is someone only show me where the spoon. 

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I've asked a couple times, and I'll ask once again. Please provide enough info for me (or anyone else) to reproduct the problem. I'm currently unable to do that, and as a result also unable to help you.